# sometimes _client.IsExistingObject(id) returns exception rather than false

Tags: core-service

In my code I'm reading a Bundle which is in workflow and eventually it get dissovled after completion of workflow. To avoid any reading error I am using IsExistingObject(bundle_tcm_id) method from core service however sometime I get following exception rather than false :

System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[Tridion.ContentManager.CoreService.Client.CoreServiceFault]: A database error occurred while executing Stored Procedure "EDA_ORG_ITEMS.READ_ORG_ITEM".
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at "TCMDBUSER.EDA_ORG_ITEMS", line 2715
ORA-06512: at line 1

Shouldn't the method retrun false if "no data found".

Answer (score 3):

I would consider that a bug, yeah. The intent of the method is clearly to prevent exceptions, so it wouldn't make sense for it to raise one unless it's a critical one like an out of memory exception.

You wouldn't happen to be deleting it within the same transaction that you are calling IsExistingObject in, would you?

Comment: No, both are completely different xactions.

Comment: And if there are cases where it should throw an exception by design, it should not be a database exception.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a timeout error on database side. The problem you are observing is most probably related to slow database. To make sure that this is indeed the case, try speeding up your database by running sp_updatestats stored procedure and by rebuilding indexes. Also check the timeout in MMC snap-in for short and long database operations. It might be too low.